# Как обратиться к нескольким элементам HTML одного класса в js

Tags: javascript, html, массивы, классы

Итак, есть у меня вот такая конструкция:

```
const PC_Card_Hand = document.querySelector('.comp-card-hand1');
PC_Card_Hand.appendChild(DECK_PC[0].getHTML());
```

Она считывает первое значение из массива `DECK_PC`, а затем создает элемент `DIV` с классом `card` с данными из массива в элементе `div` с классом `comp-card-hand1` и все прекрасно работает. Вот только есть две проблемы:

1. Элементов у меня в массиве больше чем один
2. Элементов `div` с классом `comp-card-hand1` тоже больше чем один

А все попытки как-то данный процесс зациклить и заставить элементы из массива расставляться в свободные `div`ы не приводят ни к чему хорошему и все данные упорно запихиваются в самый первый найденный элемент `div` с классом `comp-card-hand1`

Итак вопрос: как мне решить данную проблему и заставить данные из массива записываться в разные (свободные) `div` с классом `comp-card-hand1`?

**УТОЧНЕНИЕ**: массив содержит в себе 50 элементов, а элементов  `div` с классом `comp-card-hand1` 3 штуки. Я хочу, чтобы в эти дивы вставлялись первые 3 значения массива DECK_PC. А если какой-то из них освобождается, то туда должен вставляться следующий по очереди элемент.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Действительно нужно использовать `querySelectorAll()`, но так как это меняет тип данных в переменной, то обращение к ее элементам так же необходимо изменить, словно это элементы массива и соответственно, чтобы записать значение какого-то элемента вашего массива в конкретный `div` класса `.comp-card-hand`, необходимо сначала указать номер этого элемента `[i]`, а если необходимо заполнить все элементы, то лучше организовать все это через цикл.

```
const PCHand = document.querySelectorAll('.comp-card-hand');
for (var i = 0; i < DECK_PC.length; i++) {
    PCHand[i].appendChild(DECK_PC[i].getHTML());
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.comp-card-hand1');
//                                  ^^^
```

Comment: Такой вариант я попробовал один из первых. В результате, консоль выдала ошибку: `Uncaught TypeError: PC_Card_Hand.appendChild is not a function at battle.js:4:16 (anonymous) @ battle.js:4`

Comment: @drakoblack, потому что у массивов нет appendChild.

Comment: а причем здесь массив, когда речь идет о `div` с классом `comp-card-hand1` у которого `appendChild` создает `div` с классом `card` в который уже передает данные из массива? С элементом `querySelector` все работает прекрасно, но только на 1 див, а у меня их несколько. При использовании `querySelectorAll` консоль начинает ругаться...

Comment: @Ceri, ну только не совсем массив, но примерно)

Comment: вот автор вопроса написал хороший развёрнутый ответ. есть чему поучиться, правда?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, подозреваю, что если хорошо порыть, у этого вопроса пачка дубликатов нароется... Но вообще да, расписал хорошо.

Comment: вообще я как бы прозрачно намекал, что ответ, под которым я написал комментарий, ввиду его чрезмерной краткости и полному отсутствию каких-либо объяснений стоило опубликовать в виде комментария. // ну а ещё лучше было найти дубликат, конечно, но это уже за гранью возможного. // прошу прощения, если, как обычно, переборщил с сарказмом.